# Solve the equation $x^2-5+\sqrt{2x^4-20x^2+49}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $$x^2-5+\sqrt{2x^4-20x^2+49}=0$$
I am trying to simplify the square root, more precisely $$2x^4-20x^2+49=\left(\sqrt2x^2\right)^2-20x^2+7^2$$
but this leads to nowhere. In the worst case (if we can't do something else), we can write the equation as $$\sqrt{2x^4-20x^2+49}=5-x^2,$$ square both sides and check at the end or see if the solutions satisfy the inequality $5-x^2\ge0$. It won't be that bad, because we will get a biquadratic equation. I would appreciate it if you gave me a hint. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $x=2$ is a solution. Have you tried using long division with $(x-2)$?

Comment: Squaring yields a simple quartic which is quadratic in $x^2$.

Comment: Yes you are on the right track with the second approach. It will simplify if you square both sides.

Comment: @MathLover, no it won't? We will have $$2x^4-20x^2+49=25-10x^2+x^2$$ which isn't quadratic.

Comment: I deleted that part of my comment.  I don't see the point of introducing $\sqrt 2$ and such, but I do see where you got it.  The point is to notice that the quartic is just a quadratic in $x^2$.

Comment: No I am not saying it will become a quadratic but it will factorize.

Comment: @MathLover, yep, I got it. The solutions are $\pm2$. $\pm6$ isn't solution to the equation.

Comment: yes you get $x^4 - 10x^2 + 24 = 0 \implies (x^2 - 6)(x^2-4) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Put $x^2=y$
The equation simplifies to $\sqrt{2y^2-20y+49}=5-y$.
Squaring we get $y^2-10y+24=0$.
$⇒y=4,6$
$⇒x=2,-2,\sqrt{6},-\sqrt{6}$
Verifying the solutions we get that only $x=2,-2$ as the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the equation :$$x^2-5+\sqrt{2x^4-20x^2+49}=0$$

Step 1 : $$\sqrt{2x^4-20x^2+49} \space = (5-x^2)$$

Step 2 : square both sides $$2x^4-20x^2+49= x^4-10x^2+25$$

step 3 : solve for x $$x^4-10x^2+24 = 0 $$

step 4 : suppose $x^2 = a$ $$a^2-10a+24$$

step 5 : $$a =\frac{+10\pm\sqrt{100-96}}{2} = 6,4$$

step 6 : use $\space x^2 = a $ $$ x = \pm \sqrt{6}, \space \pm 2  $$

Plug those solutions to verify which satisfies the equation